# Scala Spark Column Parser with Seq and case class

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, sequence

I have a Address DataFrame with three columns like :
"addressId", "customerId", "address".
The values in the Address.csv looks like :
A100,C100,"100, ABC Street,MyCity,MyCountry".

The case class of Address AddressRaw looks like :

```scala
  // Define your case class for AddressRaw
  case class AddressRawData(
    addressId: String,
    customerId: String,
    address: String
  )
```

There is one more case class which looks like :

```scala
case class AddressData(
    addressId: String,
    customerId: String,
    address: String,
    number: Option[Int],
    road: Option[String],
    city: Option[String],
    country: Option[String]
  )
```

I want to create a dataframe 'AddressData' with all respective columns as mentioned in AddressData. Address from Addressraw Dataframe needs to be passed into a parser to get number,road,city and country.
Below is the code that I have used, which gives me error :

`Can not resolve 'number'`. It's coming as number is not part of Address Dataframe.

Here is the sample code that I Tried :

```
// ... (other imports and definitions)

object CustomerAddress extends App {
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("CustomerAddress").getOrCreate()
 import spark.implicits._
 Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

 // Define your case classes
 case class AddressRawData(
   addressId: String,
   customerId: String,
   address: String
 )

 case class AddressData(
   addressId: String,
   customerId: String,
   address: String,
   number: Option[Int],
   road: Option[String],
   city: Option[String],
   country: Option[String]
 )

 case class AccountData(
   customerId: String,
   accountId: String,
   balance: Long
 )

 case class CustomerAccountOutput(
   customerId: String,
   forename: String,
   surname: String,
   accounts: Seq[AccountData]
 )

 // ... (addressParser and other definitions)

 val addressDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", "false").csv("src/main/resources/address_data.csv")
   .toDF("addressId", "customerId", "address")

 val customerAccountDS = spark.read.parquet("src/main/resources/customerAccountOutputDS.parquet").as[CustomerAccountOutput]

    // Define your addressParser function
 def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData]): Seq[AddressData] = {
   unparsedAddress.map(address => {
     val split = address.address.split(", ")
     address.copy(
       number = Some(split(0).toInt),
       road = Some(split(1)),
       city = Some(split(2)),
       country = Some(split(3))
     )
   })
 }

 // Apply the addressParser function to the address column
 val parsedAddress = addressDF.as[AddressData].groupByKey(_.customerId).mapGroups {
   case (customerId, addresses) => customerId -> addressParser(addresses.toSeq)
 }.toDF("customerId", "address")

 // Join the customerAccountDS and parsedAddress to create the final CustomerDocument
 val finalDF = customerAccountDS.join(parsedAddress, Seq("customerId"), "inner")
   .select(
     $"customerId",
     $"forename",
     $"surname",
     $"accounts",
     $"address"
   ).as[CustomerDocument]

 // Show the records in the final DataFrame
 finalDF.show(false)
}
```

Comment: please attache files which you have used in code.. it will help us to test local and give solution.

Comment: @Srinivas Here is the AddressRaw.csv file looks like :
"addressId", "customerId", "address"
A100,C100,"100,ABC Street,MyCity,MyCountry"
A200,C200,"200,ABC StreetOne,MyCityone,MyCountryone"

Comment: Can you just read and print customerAccountOutputDS ? Also your splitting is not suitable for provided example: in example there is no space after comma.

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't really clear but code wise you can't nest case classes inside of objects, the spark.implicit's functions to generate encoders won't find them properly.  Unfortunately this results in a runtime error instead of compile time.

Re write it so you have the case classes as top levels e.g.:

```scala
 // Define your case classes
 case class AddressRawData(
   addressId: String,
   customerId: String,
   address: String
 )

 case class AddressData(
   addressId: String,
   customerId: String,
   address: String,
   number: Option[Int],
   road: Option[String],
   city: Option[String],
   country: Option[String]
 )

 case class AccountData(
   customerId: String,
   accountId: String,
   balance: Long
 )
...

object CustomerAddress extends App {
 val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").appName("CustomerAddress").getOrCreate()
 import spark.implicits._
 Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.WARN)

....
```